# When is mental illness a meaningful failure of wisdom?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, aristotle, socrates, philosophy-of-psychology, mental-illness

Some philosophers think mental illness is a failure of [function](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/28251), to act rationally, others a failure of [doing](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2215948), but it can also at least involve failures of self appraisal, to accurately judge what is good and bad about ourselves, be that due to psychosis or damaged self worth.

Does that make for a lack of wisdom and "the unexamined life" or is that somewhat different? If it does, is our life "not worth living" - whether or not we can know that?

Comment: There're many causes of mental illness, but when it's related to the absence of wisdom there're famously fifty possible causes as fully explained in the Shrurangama sutra: *this person contemplates the source of transformations. Seeing the movement and flow, he says there is change. Seeing the continuity, he says there is constancy. Where he can perceive something, he says there is production. Where he cannot perceive anything, he says there is destruction...He says that the arising of all things is existence and that the perishing of all things is nonexistence...led to inconsistent views...*

Comment: Indeed, and most unfortunate it is.

Comment: @AgentSmith i am not sure. like i said in my answer, there any many overlapping ideas about wisdom. life amounts to whatever it is

Comment: there is always something we can accurately judge about our "life" @AgentSmith even if we cannot see what we might want

Comment: Hi @prof_post, si, that is a valid point you make there. As I said, most unfortunate or one of the options you were so magnanimous to inform us of. Have a good day, mon ami.

Comment: yes i'm a clairvoyant lol i can just tell @AgentSmith

Comment: thinking about this again @AgentSmith you gotta be the person you want to be, right? that's what the examined life is???

Comment: @prof_post, oui, that is genuine concern for many folks.

Comment: @AgentSmith i just mean that without awareness of who you are or want to be you will struggle to be who you want. whatever reasons you want to agree are fine ha

Comment: @prof_post, that is correct. Such issues have been part of the journey of life.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED 2023-09-01

The concept of 'mental illness' in the [analytic tradition of philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_philosophy) is a source of philosophical contention among those who study the [philosophy of psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_psychology), and some issues run right back into metaphysical debates of issues stemming from [mind-body duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind%E2%80%93body_dualism). **A prominent question is 'To what extent is mental illness a function of the body, and to what extent a function of the mind?'.** There isn't a clear demarcation between them, and notably after the heyday of [philosophical and psychological behaviorism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behaviorism), cognitive and humanist psychologists reasserted themselves and the view that might be described as a wholesale rejection of the classical behaviorist methodology that could be construed as complementing [eliminative materialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliminative_materialism) in its metaphysical presuppositions. Famous psychologists who began pushing back on behaviorism and mental illness as strictly a physical condition were Rollo May, Abraham Maslow, others. [Humanistic psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanistic_psychology) has been tremendously impactful on the analysis of the term 'mental illness', and has roots in the Continental philosophy and the humanist tradition. Today, another school of psychology has come into being spurred on by Martin Seligman: [positive psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_psychology). From WP's article on humanistic psychology:

> The modern humanistic approach has its roots in phenomenological and existentialist thought (see Kierkegaard, Nietzsche, Heidegger, Merleau-Ponty and Sartre). Eastern philosophy and psychology also play a central role in humanistic psychology, as well as Judeo-Christian philosophies of personalism, as each shares similar concerns about the nature of human existence and consciousness. For further information on influential figures in personalism, see: Emmanuel Mounier, Gabriel Marcel, Denis de Rougemont, Jacques Maritain, Martin Buber, Emmanuel Levinas, Max Scheler and Karol Wojtyla.

**Positive psychology, which can be seen as a moderate position between extreme humanistic thinking and behaviorist thinking, recognizes the biological basis of some mental illnesses, which is essentially an irrefutable proposition given the advances in cognitive science. But it also takes the view that wisdom is a legitimate object of study that has an impact on one's mental well being.** In this sense, it complements the majority of approaches in psychotherapeutics which relies not on pharmaceutical strategies, but talk therapy and alignment of the individual views and personality with a contemporary and scientific view of the world. For instance, the notion of [cognitive distortions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_distortion) plays heavily in the treatment of depression in [CBT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_behavioral_therapy). Many modern strategies to reduce one's "friction with the world" often are essentially metaphysical in nature, with the examination of one and one's subjective experience the core of the therapeutic experience.

There is still the old-fashioned belief that mental illness is a question of exclusively using the [medical model in a psychological thinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_model). The medical model (which is the abuse of the biomedical model) is a criticism of behaviorist thinking that stems back to a movement in psychology and psychiatry called [anti-psychiatry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-psychiatry). And given successes in treating schizophrenia and other diseases with medication, availing oneself of psychiatry and the [biomedical model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biomedical_model) is a good strategy in some cases. **But drugs and surgery have limits, and the preponderance of anxiety and stress people have in life have nothing to do with extremes of abnormal psychology** in the strict sense, that is, examining distress, disease, deviance, and danger so severe that incarceration is necessary. Rather, there's a spectrum from optimal to sub-optimal to dysfunctional, and most people suffer some form of "emotional sniffles".

There is inevitably a social component to physical and mental health, and studying philosophy and wisdom to reduce mental distress and illness is a central core tenet of positive psychology. In this way, modern psychological practice has come full circle to the [ataraxia of the Stoics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataraxia) and the [eudaimonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudaimonia) of Ancient Greece more broadly. **In this sense, mental illness is always a failure of wisdom when it can't be determined to be biological in basis.** And "a failure of wisdom" in English means nothing more specific than a lack of wisdom is associated with the failure that corresponds nicely to the sub-optimal outcomes of observable behavior which is necessarily vague since sub-optimal is inherently a normative term.

See also:

- [Is "mental illness" really a disease, an illness? (PhilSE)](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/21167/40730)
- [What is a disorder? (PhilSE)](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/89668/40730)
- [Can happiness be purely a state of mind? (PhilSE)](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/98102/40730)
- [University of Chicago's Center for Practical Wisdom](https://wisdomcenter.uchicago.edu/)

Comment: you didn't answer the question directly enough for me to vote, sorry

Comment: You needn't apologize. :D The question is answered, but implicitly so. My response is for the community more broadly.

Comment: I made the thesis explicit: mental illness is always a failure of wisdom when it can't be determined to be biological in basis. That's the conclusion stemming from the philosophy that supports the postivistic school of psychology.

Comment: I also added the UoC's Center for Practical Wisdom to plug the organization. It is an institution devoted to the practical integration of wisdom into one's life to achieve an optimal psychology. I highly recommend subscribing to their newsletter. Sorry for the 'plug' ; )

Comment: i assume you mean the sufferer's wisdom? i dislike this claim, as it seems to compound the stigma of mental illness. if it isn't biological then it's their fault, etc., when presumably mental illness is either biological or due to social pressures

Comment: A logical disfunction, leading to "mental illness" isn't necessarily a failure in wisdom, because it may be happening out of reach of awareness. It might happen due to conflicts in the model we build of life, the universe, everything, and attempts to rationalise lead to blind alleys in thinking, which can cause mental disturbance. That is where cognitive therapy may help, to expose and resolve these conflicts.

Comment: i agree it's far too ambitious to say that all mental illness is a failure of wisdom. sometimes it can lead to problems with wisdom, in the same way it can to problems at work or in relationships. NTS @WeatherVane

Comment: @prof_post Failure of wisdom is an odd expression. If it fails, surely, it isn't wisdom? But I agree it seems, and will usually be taken, to imply that it is the sufferer's fault and they will be sent off to learn to do better. This is just as outrageous as the similar idea about physical illness that is becoming more and more popular. It is true, that the sufferer may be unaware of the failure, which may be due to an environment that failed to provide the opportunity to learn wisdom, or even actually prevented it - social deficiencies or pressures.

Comment: First, "a failure of wisdom" in English means nothing more specific than a lack of wisdom is associated with the failure. For instance, if a military suffers a defeat in an operation and it is ascribed to a "failure of intelligence", this can't be ascribed to infantry, NCOs, officers, equipment, organization, whatever. In the case of failure of wisdom, I had absolutely intended it to encompass a plurality of causes, such as wisdom on part of society, wisdom on the part of the sufferer, wisdom on the part of the treatment or lack of treatment. Secondly, wisdom in this entire conversation...

Comment: isn't defined, and I used in the sense of "decisions leading to bad outcomes" in contrast "decisions leading to outcomes" which is more inline with the spirit of intelligence. Most people who have mental illness aren't unintelligent, but rather use their intelligence to cause themselves and others distress, dysfunction, deviance, and danger. Mental illness is a VERY broad term which applies from everything from depression to dementia to excessive phobias to disorders of personality. Most of the time, there's very clear indicators of how problems can be solved, but those solutions...

Comment: aren't implemented. As someone who struggled with mental illness and is absolutely familiar with it and a range of treatments, I can say that both me and society, in hindsight, were both responsible, and that the my "friction with society" was a lack of wisdom from me, those closest around me, the health care system, and society in broadest terms. [Egosyntonic thinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egosyntonic_and_egodystonic) absolutely aligns with having a lack of wisdom... cognitive distortions, delusions, obsessions and compulsions, ie, ...

Comment: The idea that people with mental illness have no responsibility at all for their illness is a bit far fetched, because such a view entails that they are passive victims. Even in extreme cases where the biomedical model provides a solution, say schizophrenia, a patient, once treatment begins has some freedom to choose, to comply with meds they're required to take, for instance. And of course, in other less clear circumstances about the biological underpinning, the responsibility only increases... talk therapy would not be an efficacious treatment if it didn't involve having to make choices.

Comment: @WeatherVane "A logical disfunction, leading to "mental illness" isn't necessarily a failure in wisdom, because it may be happening out of reach of awareness." This isn't remotely true. Ignorance is no defense. Take a vulnerable narcissist who is suffering from egosyntonic logical distortions that accumulate to a clinical-grade delusion. Despite the fact that THEY don't believe they are acting unwisely, by dint of a diagnosis of personality disorder, they are now by the cumulative wisdom of society are judged to be acting unwisely despite their disagreement with society. They may be...

Comment: Emotionally harming their own children, for instance, who then pay the price for their ignorance.

Comment: @LudwigV I believe all responses have stumbled on a fair reading of "failure of wisdom" and I've addressed that above to the OP, failure of wisdom is simply a synonymous construction for living a less-than-optimal life by making less-than-optimal choices, and the greater the distance from the optimal (whatever that may be), the greater the failure of wisdom. Wisdom is by definition normative and teleological, so mental illness, broadly construed largely involves a collection of bad ideas and decisions based on those ideas. But these are empty assertions re: the synonymy of illness with bad...

Comment: illness and health are just stand-ins for vices and virtues charading as medical terms. But unless there are clear cut indicators in the biomedical model, they have little objective meaning outside of the extensive clinical frameworks, such as the DSM, which arguably are nothing more than catalogs of stable personality types that lead to suffering for those "diagnosed" and those around them.

Comment: There's much to agree with in what you say. I'm not a fan of the term "wisdom" anyway. Briefly - First, in principle, I'm very sympathetic to the bio-medical markers criterion. The difficulty is that although we know more than we did, there is so much that we don't yet know. So that idea needs to be tempered with the humility of recognizing that there are markers that we don't yet know about. Which pushes us back to symptoms. I think that Foucault put his finger on an important symptom in, I think, _Madness and Civilization_ when he tells the story of the beginning of workhouses for the poor.

Comment: The idea was that people who didn't have work needed training. However, it was found that there were people who simply could not be trained in the usual ways. Foucault's suggestion was that this was the beginning of mental illness as a recognized category. (I'm not sure I have the details right, but that doesn't matter here.) The idea that it was not their fault and somewhat more humane treatment was more appropriate took a long time to take root. But the fundamental issue is pretty clear. Naturally, ethical issues were very much bound up with this from the beginning.

Comment: @LudwigV I very much applaud the approach of being skeptical of the utility of 'wisdom' and embracing the idea that social forces may be the preponderant motivation for medicalizing behavior. Certainly, evolution and neurodiversity are intertwined, and the very nature of intelligence itself should be extended beyond brains and even bodies to social collectives. On the upside, we don't lobotomize people and homosexuality is no longer in the DSM. On the downside, it seems we're one crisis away from society backsliding into the 18th century.

Comment: And thanks for the reference to Focault.